# How do I use flexbox on multiple children in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use flexbox to apply flex-direction: column. There's two children inside my parent component but when I use flexbox on the parent component, it treats the children as one entity. Example code below.

App.js snippet

```
function App() {
  return (
          <Tasks>
            <ShowBy />
            <SortBy />
          </Tasks>
  );
```

Tasks.js snippet

```
export default function Tasks ({ children }) { 
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {children}
            <p>Tasks</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Tasks.module.css (imported as styles)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Actual Output:
[ActualOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH34P.png)

Intended Output:
Children to be displayed in a column: ShowBy first, SortBy second and then Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Issue you are getting because flex works only for the elements not for the text. Take a look at below two examples.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Show By
    Sort By
    <p>Tasks</p>
</div>
```

If you want to have them in one column wrap your text within a element such as `div`, `p`, `span`.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Show By</p>
    <p>Sort By</p>
    <p>Tasks</p>
</div>
```

In your context, you need to change inside `ShowBy` and `SortBy` components.